# How to manage a custom session in a webapp?

Tags: authentication, web-application, authorization, session-management

I was reading through the [OWASP Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Top_Ten_Cheat_Sheet) and something mentioned in the "Weak Authentication and Session Management" row did not make sense to me.

It is recommended in the Design Column, that inbuilt session management should be used and that Custom session identifiers must be stored in the native session object and should not be sent as additional headers or cookies. I don't understand the second part of the statement. If not as a header or a cookie how else can I establish/send additional session information? Isn't it standard practice to add a secure cookie for the feature I am writing for?

What is a native session object as referenced in the document?

How does it differ from the inbuilt session management?

Answer (score 2):

To quote directly:

> Only use inbuilt session management.
>
> Store **secondary SSO / framework / custom session identifiers** in native session object – do not send as additional headers or cookies.

What this is saying is that, if you've got a secondary system which doesn't/can't use inbuilt sessions, you shouldn't send that second session token as a cookie or header, but instead should put that token into your inbuilt session. That way, you have one single session token which may point to others if needed.

When they say "the native session management", they mean something like `$_SESSION` on PHP, or the `Session` object in ASP.NET, whereby the session data is stored server-side and a token is maintained on the client-side in order to identify the session for that user.

For example, let's say you've got three webapps. You later roll out a single sign-on (SSO) system so that you don't have to separately log into each. According to the OWASP guidelines, it would be a bad idea to implement it such that visiting each separate application gives you separate session tokens. Instead, the SSO should give you a single session token, which should be used for all three applications. If separate identifiers are required for each, these identifiers should be stored in the session *data*, so that they can be read from there.

The benefits of this are:

- Expiring the main session expires others automatically - no latent sessions.
- Less attack surface for cookie management issues (e.g. `Secure` or `HttpOnly` flags).
- Less likelihood of session token leakage.

A quick PHP example of how you might handle this in a webapp:

```
<?php
session_start();
$sid = isset($_SESSION['app3_session']) ? $_SESSION['app3_session'] : NULL;
if ($sid != NULL)
{
    // verify SID for this particular app
}
?>
```

The SSO would create the initial session and populate the `app3_session` value.